# Rails 3 Dragonfly uid of attachment is correct but the file iself is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, dragonfly-gem

Im using Dragonfly and Amazon s3 for the image uploads. For some reason when I upload a picture, it saves to the right folder on amazon, and the uid is the right path, but it is not showing up!

Every time I call `user.avatar` it is nil even though `user.avatar_uid` is correct. How can I get the image to display properly with `user.avatar.remote_url`?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  image_accessor :avatar do
    storage_path { |file| 
      "#{self[:id]}/avatar/pic#{rand(1000)}.#{file.format.to_s.downcase}" 
    }
    after_assign { |a| 
      self.avatar = a.jpg.thumb('300x300#n') if (VALID_PHOTO_TYPES.include? self.avatar.format)
    }
  end  

  attr_accessible :avatar_url, :retained_avatar, :avatar
  attr_reader :id, :avatar_uid
```

Comment: This baffled me for several hours so I hope nobody else has to figure this out through guess-and-check themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `:avatar_uid` in any of attr_reader, attr_writer, attr_accessible.

If you have that in your model, it will break. Pretend that the *_uid does not exist for any model with Dragonfly and only use user.avatar.